# SSRS - How to group Date into Today/Yesterday/Week/Month in a Matrix?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, expression, mdx

I have data sorted by dates:

e.g.
Region - Date - Count
East - 2012/01/01 - 5
West - 2012/01/01 - 2
East - 2012/01/06 - 3
South - 2012/01/07 - 3
etc

I'm trying to create a sum of the Counts, grouped by date groups relative to today. So for example

Assuming today was 2012/01/07:

- Yesterday is defined to be from Today - 1 to today (non-inclusive of
  today)
- Week is defined to be from Today - 7 to today  (non-inclusive    of
  today)
- Month is defined to be from Today - 28 to today (non-inclusive
  of today)

The output in the matrix for the sample data would be:

[image]

As a bonus, ideally I'd have a 5th column that's for "On Demand" Start and End date range for the user to input.

I think the key is to add an EXPR in the Column Group's Group On property but I don't know what the Expression should be.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I think I would prefer to attack it in the SQL query. So for example

```
SELECT 
 CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), DateColumn) = 0 THEN SomeColumn ELSE 0 END cToday
 CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), DateColumn) = 1 THEN SomeColumn ELSE 0 END cYesterday
 CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), DateColumn) > 0 AND 
           DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), DateColumn) < 8 THEN SomeColumn ELSE 0 END cWeek
 CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), DateColumn) > 0 THEN SomeColumn ELSE 0 END cMonth
FROM 
 SomeTable
WHERE 
 DateColumn > DATEADD(day, -28, GETDATE())
```

Otherwise you could use a similar approach inside SSRS